Cannot get full text from url using requests_html
I'm trying to parse a page from this url:
https://www.mathworks.com/help/radar/referencelist.html?type=block
I need to get all the links from the list of blocks under "Radar Toolbox — Blocks" header i.e. inside <div id="reflist_content">.
I'm using requests_html like this:
from requests_html import HTMLSession

session = HTMLSession()

url = 'https://www.mathworks.com/help/radar/referencelist.html?type=block'
r = session.get(url)

r.html.arender()

results = r.html.find('div')
res_str = ''

for item in results:
    #print(item)
    #print(item.text)
    res_str += str(item) + '\n'
    res_str += item.text + '\n\n'

The text of reflist_content in the results is empty.
I cannot find any of the needed content in the results. I tried to search by different html tags or keywords but it seems that the table with blocks is not rendered at all.
What am I doing wrong?

The data you see is loaded from external URL. TO load it you can use this example:
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.mathworks.com/help/radar/referencelist_block_cat.xml"

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "xml")

for category in soup.select("cat:has(ref)"):
    print(category.title.text)
    print()
    for r in category.select("ref"):
        print(
            f'{r.text[:40]:<40} {"https://www.mathworks.com/help/radar/" + r["target"]}'
        )
    print()

Prints:
Radar Toolbox

Backscatter signals from bicyclist (Sinc https://www.mathworks.com/help/radar/ref/backscatterbicyclistblock.html
Backscatter signals from pedestrian (Sin https://www.mathworks.com/help/radar/ref/backscatterpedestrianblock.html
Barrage jammer interference source (Sinc https://www.mathworks.com/help/radar/ref/barragejammer.html
Constant gamma clutter simulation (Since https://www.mathworks.com/help/radar/ref/constantgammaclutter.html
Constant gamma clutter simulation using  https://www.mathworks.com/help/radar/ref/gpuconstantgammaclutter.html
Generate radar sensor detections and tra https://www.mathworks.com/help/radar/ref/radardatagenerator.html
Combine detection reports from different https://www.mathworks.com/help/radar/ref/detectionconcatenation.html
Two-ray channel environment (Since R2021 https://www.mathworks.com/help/radar/ref/tworaychannel.html
Wideband two-ray channel environment (Si https://www.mathworks.com/help/radar/ref/widebandtworaychannel.html
Library of pulse waveforms (Since R2021a https://www.mathworks.com/help/radar/ref/pulsewaveformlibrary.html
Library of pulse compression specificati https://www.mathworks.com/help/radar/ref/pulsecompressionlibrary.html
Cluster detections (Since R2021a)        https://www.mathworks.com/help/radar/ref/dbscanclusterer.html

Data Synthesis

Backscatter signals from bicyclist (Sinc https://www.mathworks.com/help/radar/ref/backscatterbicyclistblock.html
Backscatter signals from pedestrian (Sin https://www.mathworks.com/help/radar/ref/backscatterpedestrianblock.html
Barrage jammer interference source (Sinc https://www.mathworks.com/help/radar/ref/barragejammer.html
Constant gamma clutter simulation (Since https://www.mathworks.com/help/radar/ref/constantgammaclutter.html
Constant gamma clutter simulation using  https://www.mathworks.com/help/radar/ref/gpuconstantgammaclutter.html
Generate radar sensor detections and tra https://www.mathworks.com/help/radar/ref/radardatagenerator.html
Combine detection reports from different https://www.mathworks.com/help/radar/ref/detectionconcatenation.html
Two-ray channel environment (Since R2021 https://www.mathworks.com/help/radar/ref/tworaychannel.html
Wideband two-ray channel environment (Si https://www.mathworks.com/help/radar/ref/widebandtworaychannel.html
Library of pulse waveforms (Since R2021a https://www.mathworks.com/help/radar/ref/pulsewaveformlibrary.html

Signal and Data Processing

Library of pulse compression specificati https://www.mathworks.com/help/radar/ref/pulsecompressionlibrary.html
Cluster detections (Since R2021a)        https://www.mathworks.com/help/radar/ref/dbscanclusterer.html

Detection, Range, Angle, and Doppler Estimation

Library of pulse compression specificati https://www.mathworks.com/help/radar/ref/pulsecompressionlibrary.html

Clustering

Cluster detections (Since R2021a)        https://www.mathworks.com/help/radar/ref/dbscanclusterer.html


Oh yes thank you for this solution! But could you please explain how you came up with this url: https://www.mathworks.com/help/radar/referencelist_block_cat.xml ? It is not mentioned explicitly on the page as I can see.

@AlexeyBogdanov Open Web developer tools in your browser, switch to Network tab and reload the page. The URL should be there.
